# Can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs index)

Tags: doctrine-odm, symfony-2.2

I'm trying to use GeoSpatial features of MongoDB. I have this Document:

```
<?php

namespace My\CoreBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 * @MongoDB\Index(keys={"coordinates"="2d"})
 */
class WorkoutLocation
{
    /** @MongoDB\Id */
    protected $id;

    /** @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="User") */
    protected $users;

    /** @MongoDB\String */
    protected $name;

    /** @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Coordinates") */
    protected $coordinates;

    /** @MongoDB\Distance */
    protected $distance;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function addUser(\My\CoreBundle\Document\User $users)
    {
        $this->users[] = $users;
    }

    public function removeUser(\My\CoreBundle\Document\User $users)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($users);
    }

    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set coordinates
     *
     * @param My\CoreBundle\Document\Coordinates $coordinates
     * @return \WorkoutLocation
     */
    public function setCoordinates(\My\CoreBundle\Document\Coordinates $coordinates)
    {
        $this->coordinates = $coordinates;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCoordinates()
    {
        return $this->coordinates;
    }

    /**
     * Set distance
     *
     * @param string $distance
     * @return \WorkoutLocation
     */
    public function setDistance($distance)
    {
        $this->distance = $distance;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get distance
     *
     * @return string $distance
     */
    public function getDistance()
    {
        return $this->distance;
    }
}
```

and Coordinates document

```
<?php

namespace My\CoreBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/** @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument */
class Coordinates
{
    /** @MongoDB\Float */
    protected $latitude;

    /** @MongoDB\Float */
    protected $longitude;

    public function __construct($latitude = 0.0, $longitude = 0.0)
    {
        $this->setLatitude($latitude);
        $this->setLongitude($longitude);
    }

    /**
     * Set latitude
     *
     * @param float $latitude
     * @return \Coordinates
     */
    public function setLatitude($latitude)
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get latitude
     *
     * @return float $latitude
     */
    public function getLatitude()
    {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Set longitude
     *
     * @param float $longitude
     * @return \Coordinates
     */
    public function setLongitude($longitude)
    {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get longitude
     *
     * @return float $longitude
     */
    public function getLongitude()
    {
        return $this->longitude;
    }
}
```

And i have this data

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("517a1f45dd1854c818000001"),
  "name" : "ABC Gym Master",
  "coordinates" : {
    "latitude" : -8.711741,
    "longitude" : 115.166538
  }
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("517a1f45dd1854c818000002"),
  "name" : "DEF Master Gym",
  "coordinates" : {
    "latitude" : -8.712292,
    "longitude" : 115.16694
  }
}

/* 2 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("517a1f45dd1854c818000003"),
  "name" : "GHI Master Gym",
  "coordinates" : {
    "latitude" : -8.68808,
    "longitude" : 115.1718
  }
}
```

View:

```
{% for location in locations %}
Name: {{ location.name }}, Distance: {{ location.distance }}
{% endfor %}
```

But when I try this code:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();

$locations = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MyCoreBundle:WorkoutLocation')
        ->field('coordinates')->near(-8.688038,115.171329)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
return $this->render('MyCoreBundle:Default:geospatial.html.twig', array('locations' => $locations));
```

It returns error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("localhost:27017: can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs index), for: { coordinates: { $near: [ -8.688038000000001, 115.171329 ] } }") in MyCoreBundle:Default:geospatial.html.twig at line 1.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have you updated your indexes?**

When you create an index (via annotations or via an external mapping file), remember to run the command that will actually create the index and an empty collection on your db:

```
app/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:update
```

Be sure to run it also on your production db.

---

**To be sure your indexes are there:**

run in the Mongo shell:

```
db.WorkoutLocation.stats();
```

Comment: In my case, this was the problem. Index is not created. Clearly explained in the error message, but I thought it'll just work just by adding Index\keys annotation. So I run ensureIndex() command on mongo shell. I didn't realize `doctrine:schema:update` command, it makes more easy. But make sure the collection is exist before running the `doctrine:schema:update` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use geospacial queries only on fields that are indexed proper way.
Try creating one field (say, location), which is array containing just longitude and latitude (not as key/value, just two plain values), and add 2d or 2dsphere index to it.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/

Comment: I created a field with two subfields lat and lon, but it's not array, how do you convert it into array ?